# Why the subterfuge by Salino?

Tags: character, the-sting

In *The Sting*, Loretta Salino, Lonnegan's assassin, masquerades as a waitress in a diner in order to get close to Hooker. Why the need for all the subterfuge? Considering how easily she herself was eventually killed, couldn't she have accomplished the same thing herself? Hooker was a small timer after all.

Comment: Probably yes, but would it have made for this surprising and exciting sub-plot then? Most probably related to your other question if she was necessary for the plot at all.

Comment: because a redford movie requires a leading lady that is intimate with redford's character. and salino was the least disruptive way to achieve that without tanking the pace of the movie